# How to remove a specific character, From...To the End of string in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string like this: `first/exemple/import/status/5b12f918-f2ef-436f-808c-50ea48da000` 
I need to the output like this: `first/exemple/import/`

I need to remove from `status` and so on. I thought about `remplace` but it wont work because this `5b12f918-f2ef-436f-808c-50ea48da000` is variable so it changes.
if there any function can do this please

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee the structure of the text (ie that structure won't change):

```
public static ReturnFirst(string inString){
     var path = inString.Split('//')[1];
     return $"//{path}//";
}
```

Or read the first 'x' characters of the string

Comment: thanks @jonathan for your answer, I have changed the exemple, it wont work in this solution

Comment: You added additional values into the array before 'import'. So now you'll have to take more than just the first entry in the array...